# Mostrar el nombre de la categoría padre en un array de Woocommerce en template propio

Tags: array, woocommerce

estoy desarrollando un sitio de woocommerce y en el home necesito mostrar una lista de productos aleatoria de una categoría específica. Eso está perfecto, lo puedo hacer a través de este código:

```
<?php
$args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => 6,
            'orderby' => 'rand',
        'product_cat' => 'proyectos',
           
            );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?>
<li class="product">    
<a rel="nofollow" href="<?php echo get_permalink( $loop->post->ID ) ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr($loop->post->post_title ? $loop->post->post_title : $loop->post->ID); ?>">
<?php woocommerce_show_product_sale_flash( $post, $product ); ?>
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID )) echo get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog'); else echo '<img src="'.woocommerce_placeholder_img_src().'" alt="Placeholder" width="300px" height="300px" />'; ?>
<h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<div class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></div>                    
</a>
</li>
```

Lo que necesito hacer es mostrar el nombre de la categoría padre de dichos productos. Y solo logro que se muestre la categoría hija a la que pertenecen. En este caso, la categoría padre es "proyecto"

Answer (score 0):

Puedes mostrar todas las categorias asignadas a un producto usando el código

```
$product->get_categories();
```

Aqui puedes ver que elementos puedes consultar dentro del loop

https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-easily-get-product-info-title-sku-desc-product-object/

Answer (score 0):

Un tema recurrente con las categorías en wordpress es que pueden ser varias, y a esto se suma que no siempre es seguro que al cargar los datos incluyan la categoría padre en la lista.

En el ejemplo siguiente pedimos todas las categorías del producto, seleccionamos la primera, tomamos el name ( por si es una categoría padre ) y luego preguntamos si esta categoría tiene padre, y si tiene padre tomamos el name del padre. Hay un default por si el id es incorrecto o no hay categorías asignadas.

```php
function SOes403595_get_product_cat_name_by_ID( $product_id = 0 ){
  // default a retornar
  $product_cat_name = 'unknown';

  // id debe ser entero positivo mayor que cero
  $product_id = absint( $product_id );
  if ( 0 < $product_id ) {

    // pedimos todas las categorías de producto de este producto
    $product_cats = wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat' );

    // tomamos la primer categoría ( term ) de la lista
    $product_cat = reset( $product_cats );
    // tomamos el name por si es una categoría padre
    $product_cat_name = $product_cat->name;

    // si es una categoría hija de alguien el parent va a ser distinto de cero
    $product_cat_parent_id = $product_cat->parent;
    if( 0 != $product_cat_parent_id ){
      // si hay parent, pedimos el term ( categoría )
      $parent = get_term_by( 'id', $product_cat_parent_id, 'product_cat' );
      // tomamos el name
      $product_cat_name = $parent->name;
    }
  }
  // retornamos el name
  return $product_cat_name;
}
```

Tener en cuenta que al agregar nueva categoría y sub categoría desde agregar/editar post ( o producto en este caso ) se agrega la jerarquía "correctamente" ( fig 1 )

[image: categoria padre e hija asignadas al crear]

Pero al cargar un nuevo post ( o producto ) puede que se especifique sólo la categoría hija ( fig 2 ).

[image: subcategoría ya existente seleccionada al crear post/producto]

Esto por lo general ocurre cuando la lista de categorías es mas larga que la caja que las muestra ( fig 3 )

[image: al seleccionar una subcategoría de una lista larga se puede perder la referencia]

Dependiendo de cómo sea el resultado esperado en casos de varias categorías de mismo padre, o de padres diferentes, o que tan definido esté el procedimiento de carga de productos ( si es automatizado habrá mas control ) las soluciones varían.

En el caso de tener listados dinámicos de productos que poseen varias categorías de posiblemente diferentes padres, ahí habrá que modificar el código para buscar el padre correcto de entre todos los posibles padres, y si ves que falta alguno verificar que el producto tenga asignados tanto la categoría hija como la categoría padre.

Marcar como categoría principal la categoría padre o la sub categoría también puede influir en cómo se listan o filtran los productos, según cómo los muestres en el theme o si usas plugins, custom loops, los blocks o shortcodes de woocommerce, etc. ( ver fig 1 "Primary"/"Make primary" ).